# Counting breeds within an agentset

Tags: netlogo

If I have an agentset called zoo belonging to turtle 1, how do I count all the breed of camels in the zoo? NetLogo has a breed-on command, but not a breed-in. So this won't work, although it will illustrate what I'd like:

```
ask turtle 1 [let c count camels-in zoo]
```

Thanks.

Comment: So the agentset zoo has turtles of different breeds in it?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is you want something like:

```
let c count ([zoo] of turtle 1) with [breed = camels]
```

But an example of a zoo turtleset would be very helpful in understanding what you are trying to do. Perhaps also what your turtles are representing?

Comment: I didn't realise there is a breed variable. I expect that's exactly it, thank you.